# How to start working using a GA

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am very new to the topic of genetic algorithms and am trying to understand some of the GA concepts defined here and there.

My questions are about how to start thinking about getting a solution for a problem using a GA. I have a small database with about 3000 entries, where mobile prepaid subscribers' usage patterns are given. I need to identify the spending pattern of these customers and what to offer them next so that their overall spending is likely to increase.

At the moment I am brainstorming about how the GA chromosome should be encoded, what the fitness function should look like, how to create the first population, and what the criteria of crossover functions, etc. should be.

Could any expert give some advice on how I can proceed for this type of problem?

Comment: You're certain on the method, though you have not yet fully developed your problem... At this stage I wouldn't yet decide on a GA already. Please elaborate on what a "spending pattern" is and how it looks like. Since you want to identify a spending pattern, I think you should formalize it first.

Comment: I would go with a learning algorithm rather than a genetic algorithm. Genetic algorithms are for optimization and learning algorithm are for classification (or identifying patterns).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have to realize is that GA is an optimization technique. 
So for the first part of your problem (identifying the spending pattern) what do you need to optimize? A GA is a "smart" way of guessing solutions. In this case it will guess spending patterns. What you need is a way of comparing guessed spending patterns in order to progressively choose the best. This comparison is made with a cost function which is what you want to optimize.
The first thing you need to do is try to model your problem as an optimization problem. How do you describe a spending pattern in relation to the usage pattern (which is your input). How do you compare spending patterns? Once you have defined these things you can start worrying about the specifics of the GA, but only after!
The second problem (find what to offer them) once you have their spending pattern is to maximize this function (the spending pattern function), and this you can do again with GA or using some other optimization technique.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for a supervised regression technique. You can define a (possibly very large) set of features that define each subscriber's spending habits. You can then run a regression algorithm to work out which of the features correlate with high spending. For instance, you may find the "promotions offered this month" correlates positively with spending, so to increase your profits you should offer more discounts, etc. Engineer your features so that they correspond to things you can affect- if you include age and sex (for example) in your feature set, you may well find these are important spending indicators. Unfortunately, you cannot change the age or sex of your subscribers.